# gcc 4.8.1 compiling .c files as c++ in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gcc, g++, ubuntu-12.04, language-interoperability, gcc4.8

One of my users is getting an error message when trying to compile a C part of our mixed C/C++ codebase on ubuntu 12.04 with gcc 4.8.1

We have a library in C++ with some C-linkage functions in, and want to compile a C program linking to it.  The library is compiled with g++ and builds fine.  The c program fails like this:

```
> gcc -O3 -g -fPIC -I/media/Repo/lcdm/code/cosmosis/ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -std=c99 -o c_datablock_t c_datablock_test.c -L . -lcosmosis

cc1plus: error: command line option ‘-std=c99’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [-Werror]
```

The program has a lower case .c file suffix, so why does gcc try to compile it as c++ ?  We have not seen this on other OSes.

(I know we could kick the problem down the road by removing -Werror or handle this particular file with -x c but I'd like to solve the real problem.)

Comment: Do you get the same error if you copy/paste the one line posted here to compile the file in a terminal in the proper directory ?

Comment: Thanks nos - I've asked our user to try that.

Answer (score 0):

> why does gcc try to compile it as c++

I can think of only two plausible explanations, and they both are end-user's fault.

- It could be that the user transferred sources via Windows, and the file is really called `C_DATABLOCK_TEST.C`, and the user is misleading you.
- It could also be that the user overwrote his `gcc` with `g++` (surprisingly many people believe that `gcc` and `g++` are the same thing, but they are not).

To disprove the first possibility, ask the user to execute his build commands under `script`, and send you resulting `typescript`.

To disprove the second, ask the user to add `-v` to the compile command.

Answer (score -1):

This look like GCC Bug 54641,   which has been fixed in a later release of GCC.   It is only a warning,   but your compile flags are causing GCC to treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: This looks nothing like gcc bug 54641